# Can't add ResourceDictionary to App.xaml

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, resourcedictionary, template10

I'm currently using T10 for developing a simple app, by using Blank template. Then, I saw from Hamburger template that you apply Custom.xaml theme into App.xaml by adding `Application.Resource` into `App.xaml` like this

```
<common:BootStrapper x:Class="T10Hamburger.App" 
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                     xmlns:common="using:Template10.Common">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Custom.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>

</common:BootStrapper>
```

I did the same thing into my project, but I'm getting XAML exception.

Here is the message from the exception :

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component."

Did I miss something?

nb : A little note, when I tried to manually type the  `Application.Resource`  into App.xaml, the Intellisense didn't catch the  `Application`  part, but later show when I tried to complete it with `Resource`

Comment: Post the exception/error, please.

Comment: Take a look at question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852051/adding-basedon-style-on-app-xaml-is-crashing-on-app-initializecomponent). Looks like styles that are `BasedOn` other styles cause the problem. See if you issue goes away after removing the offending styles. Mine did.

Answer (score 2):

For me your issue is here:

`<Application.Resources>` it should be  `<common:BootStrapper.Resources>`

In other words you should have:

```
<common:BootStrapper x:Class="T10Hamburger.App" 
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                     xmlns:common="using:Template10.Common">

    <common:BootStrapper.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Custom.xaml" />
    </common:BootStrapper.Resources>

</common:BootStrapper>
```

Comment: still got the exception (also Intellisense can't detect the `BootStrapper` when I tried to add). But your answer debunks one of my what-if, so thank you

Comment: what version of Template 10 are you using? are the samples working for the Template 10 project?

Comment: Can you zip your solution for me and let me have access?

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AC96A64BA8AD567E!395631&authkey=!AJ6ARwQaPkR5KBM&ithint=file%2c7z

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio was the solution for me.